# Angular: this.categories is undefined

Tags: javascript, angular

I have  weird issue at the moment that I can't wrap my head around. The situation is as following.

When I initiate the component I subscribe to a subject in my forum service. This subject sends me the name of the forum category of which the server just sent its posts. After I receive this category name I adjust my component properties so I can display them dynamically in my template.

The issue is as following. I have a component array property called `categories`. This contains the descriptions of the category that I want to display. I want to iterate through this array and if the name from the service matches the category name it returns the index. However, I am not able to select this.categories in the subscribe method. I first thought it was an issue with `this`, but then I checked if I could select other properties like `title` and this did not return `undefined`.

Does someone know what's causing this and how to solve it?

**Forum header component: I console logged both this.title and this.categories. the first returned what I had hoped, but the second returns undefined**

```
export class ForumHeaderComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  title: string;
  description: string;


  categories: [
    {name: 'Quests', description: 'Join others on a quest, ask for advice on one or start one yourself.'},
    {name: 'Cities', description: 'Discuss the game and strategy with people in your area. '},
    {
      name: 'Houses',
      description: 'Slytherin, Gryffindor, Ravenclaw or Gryffindor. Ask for advice and discuss strategy with people from your house.'},
    {name: 'Tips & tricks', description: 'Have a trick you would like to tell others about? Or learn from others to improve your game?'},
    {name: 'General', description: 'Join existing topics in one of our various categories or start a your own discussion'}
    ];


  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private forumService: ForumService) { }



  ngOnInit() {
    this.forumService.categoryOfTitle.subscribe( (category: any) => {
      if (category !== 'general') {

            this.title = category;
            console.log('this.title', this.title);
            console.log('category', category);
            console.log('this.categories', this.categories);
            const index = this.categories.findIndex( categoryProperty => {
              return categoryProperty.name.toLowerCase() === category;
            });
            this.description = this.categories[index].description;
            console.log('description result', this.description);
      } else if ( category === 'general') {
        this.main = true;
            this.title = 'Welcome to the Harry Potter: Wizards unite fans forum.';
            this.description = 'Join existing topics in one of our various categories or start a your own discussion';
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Declare `categories = [ ... ]` (with an equal sign).

Comment: Oh god *facepalm*

Comment: Thanks Connor, appreciate it. Seems like I need to take a break now.